# How to create a model from drawings just like Smoothie-3D, Paint 3D or Monster Mash?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, grease-pencil, tools

[image]

I want to find some way to imitate [this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4whM0VVYlwQ). (draw a curve that becomes a model with a few clicks)

The same can be done with **Paint 3D** as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_gqSQLCKU0) and **Monster Mash** as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ny-p-CHNyM).

The most I can do is convert the Grease Pencil to mesh and with the vertices create a plane, but inflate it is so hard.

Does anyone know a method to imitate in Blender what is done in [Smoothie-3D](https://www.smoothie-3d.com/site/page_index.php), Microsoft Paint 3D or [Monster Mash](http://monstermash.zone/#)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out how to do it. I hope the explanation below can help other users. To understand the process in more detail, I recommend the tutorial ["Blender Sculpting Tutorial: Full Advanced Creature Creation Workflow"](https://youtu.be/tQfFlzHJJ88) by CG Boost on YouTube.

---

1. With any model selected, in Sculpt Mode with the `Lasso Trim` tool, I change `Trim Mode = Join` and `Shape Orientation = View` in the header. Enable `Use Cursor for Depth` if you want to control the length of the model in proportion to the radius of the brush. The smaller the radius, the thinner the object will be.

[image]

Then I draw the shapes to create the silhouettes.

[image]

---

2. To rearrange the mesh, I use the `Remesh` command (header) after defining a `Voxel Size`.

[image]

---

3. And finally, to smooth and inflate the model to disappear with the hard edges, I use the `Mesh Filter` tool with `Filter Types = Smooth / Inflate`. Keep `X/Y/Z` active in `Deform Axis` and `Orientation = View`.

[image]

[image]

---

4. From there, any adjustment of scale, rotation and proportion can be made in Object or Edit Mode.